# Loading DLL on OSX

Tags: visual-studio, macos, dll

A repository has a C project in Visual Studio. The project is going to run on a mobile device. I am on OSX and would like to compile and contribute to the project. (Assume parallels is not an options, that I do not have a Windows license or a Visual Studio license) Just downloading the C files would be enough except they are also using DLL which are also windows only.

Is there any way I can reconstruct this in an OSX compiler so I can build the files?

Comment: This is not clear. It seems you are in need of a cross-compiler. But it's not clear to me which platform you are actually targeting.

Comment: One team is working in Windows and using DLLs in their project, instead of just .h files. I want to build the project on the machine I have here, running OSX, but I do not know of a way to use DLLs on OSX. The platforms of the machines here aren't relevant to development because the executable runs on a third kind of device using the already cross-platform SDK.

Comment: Can you use `Visual Studio Express Edition` and `Wine` or you're looking for a native cross-compiler?

Comment: I dont know, can I? If thats a solution go ahead and post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need a [cross-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) that produces a Windows binary on Mac OS X.

Have a look at the MinGW compilers for Mac OS X available [here](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php). You won't be able to use the existing Visual Studio project but MinGW should be sufficient to compile the C files and link to the provided DLLs.

Answer (score 2):

You can download and install `Wine` using `MacPorts` or you can just use `WineSkin` which is a GUI Wrapper for `Wine` on `MacOS X`. Go and grab `Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition` **ISO** image and install the application on `Wine`. Then you can open the `VS` project and try compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I think you need to run Windows DLLs on OSX without using a Windows VM. Assuming that you can't recompile the DLLs to target OSX, I think that your only realistic solution is to use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).